# App parts in SharePoint online or Office365

Tags: office-365

I have Office 365 preview online and I have not installed the sharepoint 2013 preview server locally in the system. I need to create **"App parts"** for sharepoint online using visual studio 2012.

I have

- Visual studio 2012
- SharePoint development tools

I have followed the topic below form MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179921%28v=office.15%29.aspx?lc=1033

According to the above topic I have created new project -->  App for SharePoint 2013 template--OK. Then I specify the sharepoint online site url-->AutoHosted app- OK. According to the topic the wizard must allow me to create new web project. But i dont get any option in wizard to create a new web project. Can anyone tell me where have I gone wrong or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your project will look similar to the example by selecting either AutoHosted or ProviderHosted apps. If you select SharePoint hosted app you Visual Studio Project will look nothing like their example.